# Private class attributes in C++

Tags: c++, private

I'm currently reviewing a course from school and I've run against this question.

The problem with the following code is that the attributes `x` and `y` for my `Box` class are private so can't be accessed by the `Foo` method. Still the course isn't as nice as to tell me *why* that is so I decided to ask the fine people of stackoverflow.

What code on the `//Insert line of code here` below should be added to make my current program run?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Box {
    int x,y;

    public:
    Box(int xi, int yi) 
    {
        x=xi;
        y=yi;
    }

    //Insert line of code here
}

bool foo(Box l, Box r){
    return (l.x*l.y)>(r.x*r.y);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   Box b1(3,4), b2(1,2);

   if(foo(b1,b2)) {
       cout <<"b1>b2\n";
   }
   return cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Ummmmm....`getX()` and `getY()` would be a start.

Comment: Look up "friend functions".

Comment: Your teacher expects you to add friend declaration of `foo` function. In principle it is good for you to know that such feature exists, but it would be bad if you would use it where other alternatives exist (which is almost always). `getX()` is something that you should be using in the real world.

Comment: If `foo` must be external to the class, declare it as a `friend` to allow it access to private member's. A (arguably) better option would be to give `Box` `const`, `public` methods that return a copy of the `private` members (something like `getX()` and `getY()`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of options here. If you are only allowed to add one line, you could make `foo` a friend function:

```
friend bool foo(Box l, Box r);
```

Getters are probably a better option, and you could make `foo` a static function as well, but that would take three lines (adding `Box::` in front of `foo` in the definition and in main where it is called).

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do? Do you want x and y to be modifiable? If not, add getX and getY methods that simply return the values from within the class. If you want them to be modifiable freely, drop the OO charade and just make them public, since there's no reason to try to protect them in that case.

Comment: My teacher wrote this code. I know that it's written pretty poorly. The assignment is that I need to make the code work, by just adding code to that 1 single line. So creating a getX and getY method sounds great but that would force me to modify the rest of my code which I can't do. 

Do you know how I can make the code work with JUST adding one line of code?

Answer (score 1):

Do it with some get methods:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Box {
    int x,y;

    public:
    Box(int xi, int yi) 
    {
        x=xi;
        y=yi;
    }

    //Insert line of code here
    int Box::getx(){return x;}
    int Box::gety(){return y;}
}

bool foo(Box l, Box r){
    return (l.get()*l.gety())>(r.getx()*r.gety());
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   Box b1(3,4), b2(1,2);

   if(foo(b1,b2)) {
       cout <<"b1>b2\n";
   }
   return cin.get();
}
```